# what is xyz* in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to understand Jitsi iOS code strucutre

Ps: I am new to Objective C and trying to do something similar

So this is what Jitsi Peeps are doing here

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    JitsiMeetView *view = (JitsiMeetView *) self.view;
    view.delegate = self;

    [view join:[[JitsiMeet sharedInstance] getInitialConferenceOptions]];
}
```

line: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/app/src/ViewController.m#L35

Jitsi MeetView: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeetView.h

I couldn't get what does `(JitsiMeetView *)` in objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
JitsiMeetView *view = (JitsiMeetView *) self.view;
```

is a cast from `UIView` type to `JitsiMeetView` type and `*` is used with reference types

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, You mean, this is just that view is going to be of type JitsiMeetView? if not, can you please further simplify it?

Comment: Without that line 2 lines below it will give a compile time error as usual view has no `delegate` property and `join` function to be used that's is the use of the first line

Comment: It's just a cast, it means: "Don't worry, treat it as it was a `JitsiMeetView` instance)". That way it allows you to be help by the compiler as it was an instance of it. BUT it's not magic. If in reality it's not a `JitsiMeetView`, it could crash. Be careful when using it. It a "Trust me, I know what I'm doing" sign.